# Как перемеситить компонент в битрикс

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Всем привет, ни разу не работал с битрикс, но мне нужно компонент "Иннова: Инстаграм" расположить в произвольном месте.
Когда я добавляю этот компонент в визуальном редакторе, то он отображается в самом верху страница и перегрождает контент, как мне переместить его в другое место?
Пытался залезть в код, но там столько папок, что не смог разобраться